# What is "fmsascon" as a network layer L7 protocol & what is port 16001 typically used for?

Tags: networking, azure, port, azure-networking

I'm responsible for an Azure network and various IaaS and PaaS services. I'm looking at Azure Network Watcher Traffic Anaysis that indicates ports receiving traffic including:

```
L7Protocol: fmsascon 
DestPort: 16001
```

I googled "fmsascon" and found various terse or generic content such as [IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry, pg 122](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=122):

```
fmsascon 16001 tcp Administration Server Connector [Mark_Davidson] [Mark_Davidson] 2010-10-06
 16001 udp Reserved
```

This means nothing to me.

Can someone explain what “fmsascon” is as a network layer L7 protocol and what port 16001 is typically used for?

Answer (score 0):

App Service Environments use port 16001.  The 16001 port is used for keep alive traffic between the load balancer and the ASE. If you are using an ILB ASE then you can lock traffic down to just the 454, 455, 16001 ports.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/network-info